# Bootstrap DateRangePicker language on Range setting

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I know I can use the `locale` setting to define Bootstrap DateRangePicker plugin language, although I can't figure out how do I define  the language for the `range` setting.

```
$('#my-calendar').daterangepicker(
{
  ranges: 
  {
     'Today': [moment(), moment()],
     'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
     'Last 7 days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
     'Last 30 days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
     'This month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')]
  }
}
```

I would like to change `today`, `yesterday`, etc to the defined language. So I tried without success:

```
var lang = JSON.parse($('#lang').val());
/*
 * lang[0] = 'Today'
 * lang[1] = 'Yesterday'
 * lang[2] = 'Last 7 days'
 * lang[3] = 'Last 30 days'
 * lang[4] = 'This month'
 */
$('#my-calendar').daterangepicker(
{
  ranges: 
  {
     lang[0]: [moment(), moment()],
     lang[1]: [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
     lang[2]: [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
     lang[3]: [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
     lang[4]: [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')]
  }
}
```

But this retrieves error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [` in every `lang[number]` line.

How do I set the right label language in the range setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** in a non-fashion way.

Basically, the DateRangePicker plugin creates a div which contains an list with `Today`, `Yesterday`, etc.

```
<div class="ranges">
    <ul>
        <li>Today</li>
        <li>Yesterday</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So after the plugin has done being initialized I change the `text`of the `li` manually.

```
$('.ranges ul li').eq(0).text(lang[0]);
$('.ranges ul li').eq(1).text(lang[1]);
```